# Set the TP/SL on opening a Futures position at the same time (Binance API)

Tags: api, binance

I'm trying to manage FUTURES order/positions through Binance API.
I know how to open a position WITH **MARKET PRICE** but I WANT TO **SET THE TP/SL** (Take profit & Stop loss) **AT THE SAME TIME**.

As I mentioned I want to use MARKET as the order type so I don't know the price. I want add 50% to the market price and put it as TP (Take profit) and add -%70 as SL (Stop loss) [like below image]

[image]

It would be highly appreciated if you help me with the rule and syntaxes.